# "angular-flex-layout" not adding margin for "mat-form-fields" on mobile screens

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout, angular-material-7

I've created a responsive form using angular material and flex-layout.
It is working fine on desktop and ipad screens.

For mobile devices, I'd like to align the form fields to the center and add a margin to the left and right of the screen. Is there a way to do it in flex-layout?

If not how can it be done with custom CSS using `ngClass.xs`? I've tried setting the width to 90% but it's not centered properly and look odd.

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="2%" fxLayoutAlign="center">

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 1">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>place</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 2</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 2">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>business</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 3</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 3">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>send</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 4</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 4">
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest and most convenient would be to set [ngClass.xs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API) on flex container

```html
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" 
     fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="2%"  fxLayoutAlign="center" ngClass.xs="mobileContainer">
```

where `.mobileContainer` is

```css
.mobileContainer mat-form-field {
  margin: 8px 16px;
}
```

here is a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dufpaa

as a side note;

you don't need `fxFlex.xs="90%"` on `mat-form-field` elements because of `fxLayout.xs="column"` container has column layout on `xs` screens and `fxFlex.xs="90%"` means "take 90% of parents' height" on column layout. as `flex-shrink` defaults to `1` this doesn't make any effect.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. It would have been good if the `fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="2%"` was applied on mobile screens automatically.

Comment: i am glad that it helped. `fxLayoutGap.gt-xs` means "screens greater than xs". if you want it applied to `xs` screens as well, then just remove responsive selector and use it as `fxLayoutGap="2%"`

Comment: What I meant is, it would have been great if it added the `margin-left` and `margin-right` automatically. Instead of doing this hack with CSS.

Comment: sorry i got it wrong. `fxLayoutGap` is the space between flex items. so it is not possible to achieve what you want with `fxLayoutGap`. and imho, the thing with `ngClass.xs` is not a hack it is the way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayoutAlign="center">

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 1">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>place</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 2</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 2">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>business</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 3</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 3">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>send</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFlex="22%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <mat-label>Field 4</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Field 4">
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

change fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="2%" to fxLayoutGap="20px".